# PGF/TikZ: Relative coordinates behaving unexpected

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the below code, the second coordinate given with `-- +` seems to also update the path for further calculations. The shape I expected should look like a big Pi.

The PGF manual says about relative coordinates (page 133):

> Instead of ++ you can also use a single +. This also specifies a
>   relative coordinate, but it does not “update” the current point for
>   subsequent usages of relative coordinates. Thus, you can use this
>   notation to specify numerous points, all relative to the same
>   “initial” point [...]

It works like I expect on the first point (to the left), but for the second it doesn´t. What did I oversee?

My output looks like this:
[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) -- ++(0,3) -- +(-2.5,0) -- ++(3,0)  -- +(2.5,0) -- ++(0,-3);
\useasboundingbox(-3,-.5) rectangle (6,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That looks like what I'd expect. `++(0,3)` shifts the reference point so `+(-2.5,0)` and `++(3,0)` are measured relative to `(0,3)`. Then the reference point is shifted to `(3,3)` and `+(2.5,0)` and `++(0,-3)` are relative to that.

Comment: @cfr please see the pic. I don´t get why the reference point for the last operation is (5.5,3) and not (3,3).

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answers, I got it. I mixed up "leaving reference point" and "leaving path position from which will be continued"...

Comment: The reference point *is* `(3,3)`. So you end up at `(3,0)` when you come down 3. The `+(2.5,0)` is an excursion.

Comment: Yeah, the reference point is `(3,3)`. But I also thought the path had to start there, but it starts on `(5.5,3)`...

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes. The path is continuous unless, of course, you put a break in it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it makes sense if you plot it out visually:

[image: TiKZ movements]

- The movement marked in red is relative to the point marked by the red circle.
- Likewise, the movements marked in blue are relative to the point marked by the blue circle.
- Finally, the movements marked in green are relative to the point marked by the green circle.

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- ++(0,3) -- +(-2.5,0) -- ++(3,0)  -- +(2.5,0) -- ++(0,-3);
    \begin{scope}[yshift=-40mm,red]
      \draw [fill] (0,0) circle (1.5pt) node [right] {(0,0)} -- ++(0,3) node [below right] {3 up};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[yshift=-40mm,blue]
      \draw [fill] (0,3) circle (1.5pt)  node [above] {(0,3)} -- +(-2.5,0) circle (1.5pt) node [below right, font=\small] {2.5 to the left} -- ++(3,0) node [below, font=\small] {3 to the right};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[yshift=-40mm,green]
      \draw [fill] (3,3) circle (1.5pt)  node [above] {(3,3)} -- +(2.5,0) circle (1.5pt) node [above left, font=\small, xshift=5mm] {2.5 to the right} -- ++(0,-3) circle (1.5pt) node [left, font=\small] {3 down};
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to use it like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) -- ++(0,3) -- +(-2.5,0) -- ++(5.5,0)  -- ++(-2.5,0) -- +(0,-3);
\useasboundingbox(-3,-.5) rectangle (6,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**How?**

1. Draw a line from `(0,0)` to `(0,3)` and change the origin by `++`. New initial point is `(0,3)`
2. From `(0,3)` draw to `-2.5` left
3. Draw from `(-2.5,0)` (with initial point as `(0,3)`) 5.5 to the right and update initial point to this point.
4. Now come back by 2.5 to the left (relative to `(5.5,0)` ).
5. From here draw down by 3 units.

A single `+` moves from the point by the amount given. For example

```
\draw (1,1) - +(2,1);
```

draws line from `(1,1)` to right by 2 units *with respect to origin* and 1 unit up *with respect to origin*. On the other hand

```
\draw ++(1,1) - +(2,1);
```

draws line from `(1,1)` to right by 2 units *with respect to (1,1)* and 1 unit up *with respect to (1,1)*.

Comment: Well, that one works, and I understand why. Honestly I can think of a couple of tricks to make this work. The thing I don´t understand is why my example doesn´t work...

Comment: Wait. Why does the first `+(-2.5,0)` update the initial point to `(-2.5,3)`? It has only one `+` so according to the manual it should leave the initial point untouched.

Comment: Okay, I got it. I thought that not only the reference point but also the path position from which is continued are left untouched by `+`, but that of course is wrong. Thanks for helping me to understand :)